# Pop current UIViewController and push another one

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am current showing UIViewController `B`. I want to push UIViewController `C` and immediately remove `B` from the navigation stack while keeping all the animations. What's the best way to do this?

Final stack will be `A`, `C`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this if this is good idea but you can do it this way.

In your C viewcontroller, for instance in viewDidLoad method Put this code

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllerAfterRemove=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[viewControllerAfterRemove removeObjectAtIndex:1];
self.navigationController.viewControllers=viewControllerAfterRemove;
```

Now when you popViewController in your **C view controller**, it navigates back to **A view controller**.

Comment: I would suggest asking the array for the index of 'self', then deleting the object at index-1 (assuming that is 0 or a positive number. Secondly, I'm not sure you want to do this in viewDidLoad, rather look at using viewDidAppear (that said the above answer will probably work fine).

Comment: @DavidH I agree with your first part but regarding the second part, I would recommend to do it in viewDidLoad and rather not in viewDidAppear  because, lets say you have more viewcontroller beyond C view controller, if you push view to further after view controller C (for instance lets say C=>D view controller) then everything the app is navigated back D=>C it deletes an object from the self.navigationController.viewControllers which is unnecessary as the viewController B has already been deleted when the app navigated from B=>C.

Comment: I do some mucking around myself, and when I do this I use a flag to determine if this is second time in viewDidAppear. I was just concerned about mucking with viewControllers while the navController was animating one into view. It will either work or not; in any case there will be a solution along the lines you suggested.